# Array deconstruction syntax

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was going through Scala cook book for file handling and came across below code. Tried to run it in my IDE, but getting an error. Am I missing anything, I have never come across such syntax before for array.

```
import java.io.IOException
import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Source}

object ReadingCSVfile extends App {
  var bufferedSource = None: Option[BufferedSource]
  try {
    bufferedSource =
       Some(
         Source.fromFile(
           "C:\\Users\\pswain\\IdeaProjects\\test1\\src\\main\\resources\\finance.csv")
       )

    for(i <- bufferedSource.get.getLines()) {
      val Array(month, Income, Expenses, Profit) = i.split(",").map(x => x.trim)
      println(s"$month $revenue $expenses $profit")
    }
  } catch {
      case e : IOException => print(e.printStackTrace())
    } finally {bufferedSource.get.close()}
  }
```

Comment: This syntax is basically pattern matching applied on the left hand side of the equals sign. The array is being decomposed into named values on the left hand side.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this feature is called [Extractor Patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns) and is enabled for any object that has an `unapply`/`unapplySeq` instance method. What it does is allow you to extract the given value at the particular index (start at 0) directly into a variable.

Specifically, your problem is that you're using capitalized variable names in the extractor pattern, where the variable names should be lowercase:

```
val Array(month, income, expenses, profit) = i.split(",").map(x => x.trim)
```

Comment: @Yuvai Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Income, Expenses, Profit should start with lower case word.

Following code works

```
 val Array(month,income,expenses,profit) = i.split(",").map(x => x.trim)

 println(s"$month $income $expenses $profit")
```

above pattern is called `extractor pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

Like what others have mentioned, it's called `extractor patterns`. You can rewrite the code as

```
for(i <- bufferedSource.get.getLines()) {
  i.split(",").map(x => x.trim) match {
  case Array(month, income, expenses, profit) =>
     println(s"$month $revenue $expenses $profit")
  }
}
```